# Why does displayName not get updated? using onAuthChanged

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, redux, firebase-authentication

I am using Redux and to persist my auth. Using redux toolkit I have an action that checks `onAuthChanged` from Firebase Auth.

```
export const persistedSession = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestLogin());
    firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const currentUser = await createUserProfileDocument(user);
        currentUser.on("value", (snapshot) => {
          var data = snapshot.val();
          if (data !== null) {
            //Success
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
};
```

Then when I check if a document exists for this user and if not create one.

```
export const createUserProfileDocument = async (user) => {
  if (!user) return;

  const { uid, displayName, email } = user;
  const userReference = database.ref("users");
  userReference.once("value", (snapshot) => {
    if (!snapshot.hasChild(uid)) {
      userReference.child(uid).set({
       ...
      });
    }
  });
  return userReference;
};
```

So here is where my issue is. Upon creating my user `displayName` is always null how can I update user profile correctly? It seems like `onAuthChanged` is triggered before it can make an update so that displayName will always be null and document will not contain displayName property

```
export const registerUser = (value) => {
  const { firstName, surname, email, password } = value;
  return async (dispatch) => {
    
    firebaseAuth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(async (result) => {
        const user = result.user;
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: `${firstName} ${surname}`,
          })
         
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Unable to create user profile: ", error);
      });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `updateProfile` does not trigger `onAuthStateChanged`, as the authentication *state* doesn't change. There is no way to delay the triggering of `onAuthStateChanged` here either, as you can only set the display name after the user account has been created, which signs them in too.

Two options that I can think of:

1. Create the user, set their display name, sign them out, and sign them in again. The latter will then trigger another `onAuthStateChanged` *with*t he display name included.
2. Explicitly write the display name to the database too, when you also call `updateProfile`.

Comment: Thanks frank, I will have to change around my user.